# replace \r\n with \n so can have next line

Tags: java, string, csv, carriage-return, replaceall

i read a string from my csv file like below

```
BenFeature = fieldSet.readString("ben_feature").replaceAll("\r\n","\n");
```

the text from my file ben_feature  = "Testing \r\n working \r\n"
expecting to be in next like like below
Testing

working

but the out put still have \r\n.

but when i use dummy string

```
String testing = "Testing \r\n Working \r\n";
testing = testing.replaceAll("\r\n","\n")
```

this works perfectly.

is the fieldSet.readString is the issue?

Comment: _"is the fieldSet.readString is the issue?"_ -- you can test that by removing the `replaceAll` call and examining the contents of the returned string.

Comment: i did this and contents is exactly same , the one i give dummy and the one i read from readString.

Comment: How are you testing the contents? Did you set a breakpoint in your debugger and look at the memory? Does your file literally contain the text `\r\n`, or are you simply using that notation to describe the non-printable characters?

Comment: my file contains \r\n, tested by printing the SOP/logs

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("\\r\\n","\n");` -- I think you're confusing your file's contents with Java's string literal parsing, which turns `\r\n` into the CR and LF control codes. The string you read from file undergoes no such parsing, so you should escape the backslash character because you are trying to match a literal backslash character.

Comment: Finally worked...Thank you so much...
i tried '.replaceAll("\\r\\n","\n"); ' did not replace the \r\n but as a combination to try different i tried this '.replace("\\r\\n","\n");' it worked. Not really sure about why...

Comment: @rakshan `replaceAll("\\r\\n", "\n")` interprets the search term as regex, and in regex `\\r` is  interpreted as `\r`, but  `replace()` uses plain text. You will probably find that `replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "\n")` works.

Comment: but somehow its not...any idea? works only for replace
may be due to multiple spaces or multple \n

Comment: @Bohemian understood , i tried the replaceAll you mentioned, it worked also.
Thanks for the explaination

Comment: since `replaceAll()`'s input is a regular expression, check [Backslashes, escapes, and quoting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs)  - but using a regular expression is kind of an *overkill* here, `replace()`, which does not use regular expression, would be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that `the text from my file ben_feature = "Testing \r\n working \r\n"` which makes me assume that your text actually contains the `\r\n` as text. So instead of the control symbols for carriage return and line feed there is a character `\` followed by a character `r` and so on. That will not be picked up by your replace.

If you want to convert these occurences into actual `\n` you would have to escape the `\` like this: `\\`.

So your code should then read

```
BenFeature = fieldSet.readString("ben_feature").replaceAll("\\r\\n","\n");
```

Comment: Of course regex is completely unnecessary here, just use replace().